# Closure of a smooth algebraic variety in a Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians

Let $V,W$ be finite dimensional real vector spaces. I have a set $Z\subseteq V\times \mathbb{R}^*\times Gr(W)$, where $Gr$ is the Grassmannian manifold.

I know that $Z$ is closed smooth submanifold. In fact it is the graph of a smooth function $f:V\times \mathbb{R}^*\to Gr(W)$. Also $Z$ is an algebraic subvariety of $V\times \mathbb{R}^*\times Gr(W)$.

What can I say about the Euclidean closure $\bar{Z}$ in $V\times \mathbb{R}\times Gr(W)$. More precisely is it always algebraically closed and is it smooth?

Edit: I added that the vector spaces are real.